# C# convert string to int json

Tags: c#, json, string, int

I encounterd an error:

While using code:

```
 var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetCurrencies/v1/?key=54907d14ba8d88b17d8b4655&appid=440");
 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
 string BBPrice_low = (string)o["response"]["currencies"]["keys"]["price"]["value"];
 Console.WriteLine("\"" + BBPrice_low + "\"");
 int BPrice_low = (Convert.ToInt32(BBPrice_low));
```

But an error comes on the last line. It cant convert while the json string is "15.77", An convertable string, right?

Comment: I would suggest consulting the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx - throws `FormatException` when `value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).`

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Comment: This code should not compile, the name `BBPrice_high` does not exist in the current context. Maybe you meant `BPrice_high`, but that should also not compile because you would be trying to read an unassigned variable (*you are using the variable in the same variable declaration*). Perhaps you meant `BBPrice_low`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`15.77` is not a valid integer. Use `Convert.ToDouble()` Maybe you have also to set the CultureInfo.

```
Convert.ToDouble("15.77", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me

Answer (score 2):

int = number without fractional component. so 15.77 is not a valid integer
try different data type like float or double, if you need it in int, then you should round it

Comment: double BPrice_high = (Convert.ToDouble(BBPrice_high)); will return 1577 instead of 15.77

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
Convert.ToDouble(15.77) or Convert.ToDecimal(15.77)
```

15.77 is a `Double` data type in C#

Comment: Yeah. A `Double`, anyway the conversion is valid